# JAX-RS custom range on inputstream

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have REST service to serve mp4 contents which accept `Range` as header in the format `bytes=1000-` ,  where 1000 is the start byte. I am using `InputSteam.skip(int n)` method to skip first 'n' bytes  and returning remaining bytes.

On iphone(safari browser) I am getting Range request with value `bytes=1000-2000`So I would like to skip last bytes after 2000th byte as well. 
How can I skip those bytes?

Comment: Can you add a pre-process servlet Filter and handle case by case basis for user-agent based on browser type?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `java.io.InputStream#read(byte[], int, int)` with offset.

For example, range is 1000-3000:

`read(file, 1000, 2000)`

- 1000 - start from 1001th byte
- 2000 - length of range

Comment: I already tried   but after this videos are not getting played inputStream.read(currentBytes, 0, (int)endByte -(int)startByte + 1);

Comment: Ok, what stream impl `InputStream` you are using? Maybe it supports `java.io.InputStream#reset`?

Comment: Yes it supports #reset

Comment: As I understood from first comment, you try to read from start. So, yes, reset and then read. Or, you can create new stream. For more detailed help you need to provide code, which works with that stream.